# Type not found with typescript compiler but runs fine with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, ts-node

I have following program:

```
let m = new Map([
    ['key', 'value']
])

export function func() {
    console.log(m)
}
```

Following tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

The code runs fine with ts-node but gives following error when transpiling with tsc:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

How does `ts-node` find Map but `tsc` does not?